# need help extracting values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get the values from an object but All that I can get back is:
xyz = result; to value [object Object]

**Input:
**

```
tempOut = { ID: "7283", qty: 60.52 },
    { ID: "7280", qty: 3.75 },
    { ID: "7283", qty: 16 }

var array = [
    temphours
    ];

var result = [];
array.reduce(function(res, value) {
    if (!res[value.Id]) {
        res[value.Id] = { Id: value.Id, qty: 0 };
        result.push(res[value.Id])
    }
    res[value.Id].qty += value.qty;
    return res;
}, {});
```

**Expected output:**

```
result = { ID: "7283", qty: 76.52 },
    { ID: "7280", qty: 3.75 }
```

**Final result:**

```
7283, 76.52
7280,3.75
```

I tried Console.log but it returns:

> Error: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Console" is not defined. (threadScript#1)

Comment: Use `console` not `Console`.

Comment: What is `temphours`, is that supposed to be `tempOut`?

Comment: Why are you using `reduce()` if you're not assigning the result anywhere?

Comment: You're missing `[]` around the `tempOut` and `result` arrays in your input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an array for the data and the right property `ID` for grouping.

Spelling matters in Javascript.

```js
const
    data = [{ ID: "7283", qty: 60.52 }, { ID: "7280", qty: 3.75 }, { ID: "7283", qty: 16 }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce(function(res, value) {
        if (!res[value.ID]) res[value.ID] = { ID: value.ID, qty: 0 };
        res[value.ID].qty += value.qty;
        return res;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```